# Making Integer Vector into Binary Array with 1 at location of integer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose that I have a numpy array of integers like this: `[0,1,2,0,0,1,3]`.  How can I make it into a binary array whose non-zeros entries are defined by `[0,1,2,0,0,1,3]`, i.e.:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

I'm currently using the following code to do it:

```
dummy_indices = np.array([0,1,2,0,0,1,3])
dummy_array = np.zeros([dummy_indices.shape[0],(1+np.max(dummy_indices))])
for i in range(dummy_array.shape[0]):
    dummy_array[i,dummy_indices[i]] =1
```

Is there a faster loop-free way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,0,0,1,3]) #your init array
y = np.zeros(shape=(x.shape[0], x.max()+1))
y[np.arange(x.shape[0]), x] = 1

y
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```